# Widget form not displaying for media widgets in WordPress

Tags: widgets

I am creating a plugin where I want to display the widget's form using the following code. Widget form for media widgets is not being displayed while other widget's form is being displayed perfectly. Is this something to do with wpmedia or some other javascript files or libraries?

[image]

```
 <?php
    public static function mmth_widget_items($widget_id, $widget_key_id = 0){   
        global $wp_registered_widget_controls;   
        $control = $wp_registered_widget_controls[$widget_id];
        $nonce = wp_create_nonce('mmth_save_widget_' . $widget_id);  
        $id_base = isset( $control['id_base'] ) ? $control['id_base'] : $control['id']; 
        ?>
        <div id="widget-<?php echo $widget_id; ?>" class="widget"  data-item-key-id="<?php
        echo $widget_key_id; ?>">
            <div class="widget-top">

                <div class="widget-title-action">
                    <button type="button" class="widget-action hide-if-no-js widget-form-open" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="screen-reader-text"><?php printf( __( 'Edit widget: %s' ), $control['name'] ); ?></span>
                        <span class="toggle-indicator" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>

                </div>
                <div class="widget-title">
                    <h3><?php echo $control['name']; ?><span class="in-widget-title"></span></h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="widget-inner widget-inside">
                <form method='post'  class="mmth_widget_save_form">
                    <input type="hidden" name="widget-id" class="widget-id" value="<?php echo esc_attr($widget_id) ?>" />
                    <input type='hidden' name='id_base'   class="id_base" value='<?php echo esc_attr($id_base); ?>' />
                    <input type='hidden' name='widget_id' value='<?php echo esc_attr($widget_id) ?>' />
                    <input type='hidden' name='_wpnonce'  value='<?php echo esc_attr($nonce) ?>' />
                    <div class='widget-content'>
                        <?php
                        if ( is_callable( $control['callback'] ) ) {
                            call_user_func_array( $control['callback'], $control['params'] );
                        }
                        ?>

                        <div class='widget-controls'>
                            <a class='delete' href='#delete'><?php _e('Delete', 'mmth'); ?></a> |
                            <a class='close' href='#close'><?php _e('Close', 'mmth'); ?></a>
                        </div>

                        <?php
                            submit_button( __( 'Save' ), 'button-primary alignright', 'savewidget', false );
                        ?>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
        <?php
    }
```

Comment: Are you just saying some are collapsed by default? That's expected. They won't all appear expanded at once.

Comment: I know that they are collapsed by default. But as you can see that some of them only display delete and close button . There is not any button to upload image or audio. No text field for title. While for other widgets there respective form is being displayed nicely